# Change columns size in Firefox Developer Tools

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Is it possible to change columns width in Firefox Developer Tools? How can I do it?

When I point over column edge (like Status, etc. on the screenshot) there's no resize tool so I can see whole content.

[image: Firefox Developer Tools columns]

Comment: Judging by appearances, IE and Chrome probably forked the same original codebase as FF for their debuggers, and both have always allowed column resizing, making this particularly disappointing.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Update**: This feature is now available and enabled by default in Firefox 67. You can disable it (*are you crazy?*) using `devtools.netmonitor.features.resizeColumns` flag.

**Original answer**: As you probably know there is no option to change the column(s) size (as of FF57), the only option you have is hide/show columns. it's easy to do, just `right-click` on any column, you should see the list of columns and can select/un-select them.

But that's it?! no, you can change the column(s) size using `CSS` (hack the dev tools), here is the steps:

1. Open up the dev tools (using F12 or ...)
2. <del>Click on the **gear** button, up right corner</del> Go to `Settings`, shortcut: `F1`
3. Check this 2 options:

   - `Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes`
   - `Enable remote debugging`
4. Hit `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+I` and Click `OK` (on security prompt) to open [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox)
5. You should be able to inspect the `Dev tools` using opened Browser Toolbox
6. Play with `CSS` (*same as you do with normal web page*)
7. Save your custom `CSS` in `userChrome.css` file

Need more info about `userChrome.css`, head to [userchrome.org](https://www.userchrome.org/)

Here is steps to create/modify `userChrome.css`:

- Open up `about:support`
- Click on `Open Folder` (*in `Profile Folder` row*)
- Open/Create `chrome` directory
- Open/Create `userChrome.css` file
- Do what I said in first section

To demonstrate how it works, I change the background color of one of `Network tab`'s columns to red.

[image: Example]

And here is my `userChrome.css` file content (*for above example*)

```
.requests-list-file.requests-list-column {  
    background-color: red !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

*I used `!important` just for time's sake, don't use of that if you can*

Comment: Should this be filed as a bug?

Comment: @wensveen There is already a [bug report asking for this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1358414).

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the right-click show/hide;  Just getting rid of "Timeline" has freed it up sufficiently to be readable, but looking forward to 67.x...

Comment: Yeah I'm actually done with firefox. This is the last straw. Please, steal my information Google. I'm yours now. I'll use Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: In Firefox 66 there is no `devtools.netmonitor.features.resizeColumns` and columns are not resizable in network monitor. This is cruel. lol

Comment: @beppe9000 this flag added in v67.x (_current stable version as I'm writing_)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani that's probably what I get for using a portable version...

Answer (score 3):

While there seems to be *some* recent progress on the [feature request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1358414) and [its dependency](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1308451), the latter was created in 2016 so it's fairly safe to assume it could be a while yet before Firefox supports column resizing by default.

In the meantime, here's the CSS I've added to my `userChrome.css`:

```css
.requests-list-header-button {
    padding-inline-start: 0px !important;
    padding-inline-end: 0px !important;
}
.requests-list-method {
    min-width: 30px !important;
}
.requests-list-status {
    min-width: 40px !important;
}
.requests-list-file {
    min-width: 100px !important;
}
```

I wanted to enlarge the **File** column, but found that reducing the width of the **Status** and **Method** columns instead made a big improvement alone. The styles also remove side padding from the column headers to avoid the text being truncated with `…`.

These are the classes for the default columns:

- `requests-list-status`
- `requests-list-method`
- `requests-list-file`
- `requests-list-domain`
- `requests-list-cause`
- `requests-list-type`
- `requests-list-transferred`
- `requests-list-size`
- `requests-list-waterfall`

Note that if you reduce column widths too much, it may throw off the alignment. See [Mehdi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47545994/1359343) if you don't know where to save your `userChrome.css` or you need to find classes of other columns.