# Firefox Quantum Developer Tools Theme

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-quantum

I know you can change to Dark Theme, Light Theme or Firebug in Firefox Quantum. But I have it on Dark theme but don't like the color theme syntax of that theme. Is there a way to change it to Monokai or Material color scheme?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built-in option to add theme to Firefox dev tools (*as of FF57*), but you can change the style of Firefox dev tools using [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) and `userChrome.css`.

Check my step by step answer at [Change columns size in Firefox Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47545994/3367974).